# Lucky Six scratch tickets all have an independent probability of $0.05$

Tags: probability

Hey guys any tips would be appreciated.

Suppose Lucky Six scratch tickets all have an independent probability of $0.05$ of being a winner. Kathy will keep buying scratch tickets until she

- gets a winner or

  she has scratched 20 tickets, which ever comes first.

Let $X$ be the number of scratch tickets she buys. Find the pmf of $X$.
What is the probability she buys less than $17$ scratch tickets?

I think that the pmf is $$P(X=x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}, \quad x=1,2,3, \cdots,20$$ since the probability is constant from attempt to attempt and that we are dealing with a geometric distribution.

Furthermore, the probability that she buys less than $17$ scratch tickets is
\begin{align*}
P(X<17)&=1-(P(X=17)+P(X=18)+P(X=19)+P(X=20))\\
&=1-\sum_{x=17}^{20} p(1-p)^{x-1}=1-0.08164=0.9183.
\end{align*}
Is this a viable solution? If not can I get a few tips to tackle this kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pmf looks good.

For the next part, you must also account for the probability that you get $20$ consecutive failures.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(X<17)
&=1-[P(X=17)+P(X=18)+P(X=19)+P(X=20)+0.95^{20}]\\\\
&=0.5598733
\end{align*}$$

This can be calculated in R statistical software

```
> 1-sum(dgeom(16:19,.05))-.95^20
[1] 0.5598733
```

**CDF Approach:**

The CDF of a geometric distribution is given by

$$\begin{align*}
F_X(x)
&=P(X\leq x)\\\\\
&=1-(1-p)^x\\\\
&=1-0.95^{16}\\\\
&=0.5598733
\end{align*}$$

where in this case we wanted to find $P(X\leq16)$

**Alternative Solution:**

She will buy less than $17$ tickets only if she has a success on trial number $1,2,3,..,16$

This happens with probability

$$\sum_{x=1}^{16}p(1-p)^{x-1}=0.5598733$$

This can be calculated in R statistical software as well

```
> pgeom(15,.05)
[1] 0.5598733
```

Comment: Do you know where I can learn R ?

Comment: It can be downloaded free and you'll want to get R studio as well. There is plenty of online documentation as well as YouTube tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost correct. In particular, what is $P(X=20)$? In your formulation, it's the probability that she stops on the 20th ticket *because that was a winning ticket*. However, the problem says she stops on the 20th ticket *regardless* of whether or not it was a winning ticket (i.e. if tickets 1-19 were not winning tickets).

In short, if she unconditionally stops on ticket number $t$, then $P(X=t) = (1-p)^{t-1}$, which is a higher probability than what your model assigns it.

The rest of your setup seems to be correct, so you only need to modify $P(X=20)$.